# How do I call a global function in jquery/coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, dashing, jquery-knob

```
class Dashing.Hacircledimmer extends Dashing.Widget

  setLevel: ->
    levelToSet = '10'
    $.post '/homeassistant/dimmerLevel',
      widgetId: @get('id'),
      command: levelToSet,
      (data) =>
        json = JSON.parse data

  ready: ->
    meter = $(@node).find(".meter")
    meter.knob
      'release': (v) ->
        @setLevel

  onData: (data) ->
```

I am trying to call function setLevel after initializing meter.knob but I keep getting an error saying that the function does not exist. Ideally I would like to pass v to the function setLevel.

I did not include the constructor etc.. to keep the code short.

Can someone point out my error? Sorry, I am new to coffeescript and would really appreciate if anyone can help me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `'release': (v) ->` to `'release': (v) =>`

(`->` vs `=>`)

Comment: Thank you kind sir!